# Background won't show up and cover all divs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am wrapping everything with `<div class="bg-wrapper">`, however I was not able to make it cover up and display the background in the whole wrapping elements.

```css
.bg-wrapper {
  background-image: url('img/bg-background-jpg');
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="bg-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <img src="img/phone.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h1 class="display-4">I CAN DO ALL</h1>
          <h3>THINGS NOW</h3>

          <h4>Your love is a squery button ok with that?</h4>
          <p class="lead">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Sign Up Today</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

And then on my CSS file I am trying to wrapped the navigation and jumbotron with background image but it wont let me to:

Any idea how can I fixed this? I really need to wrap everything within an image background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NMKRzW)

CSS:

```
.bg-wrapper{
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/300');
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header class="bg-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
               <img src="img/phone.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
        <h1 class="display-4">I CAN DO ALL</h1>
        <h3>THINGS NOW</h3>

        <h4>Your love is  a squery button ok with that?</h4>
        <p class="lead">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Sign Up Today</a>
        </p>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </header>
```

I think your issue may lie in the image link. Make sure your link is 100% absolute.

Comment: This is bootstrap. if you do it like that it wont cover up the jumbotron.

Comment: What do you mean it won't cover up the jumbotron? You want it to overlay so you cannot see the jumbotron? As it is right now it's adding a background image to the whole header.

Comment: I already fixed by removing the background of jumbotron. Thanls snack overflow.